# SpinEdit vertically aligned buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2. I'm trying to display spinedit buttons next to an input control. Currently I've got it looking like this:

[image]

using the following HTML:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="input-mini" type="text">
    <span class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn">
            <i class="icon icon-chevron-up"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn">
            <i class="icon icon-chevron-down"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

You can see a live demo here:

http://geersch.github.io/ui.cg/#/api/cg.ui.directive:numberinput

However I'm trying to get it to look more like the default look and feel for a spinedit control:

[image]

Is it possible to align them like this next to the input, without any custom CSS?

Comment: I don't think so... adding some custom CSS rules will probably solve the problem much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Add this class to vertical align `btn-group` : **`btn-group-vertical`**

**The doc** : http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonGroups

**HTML** :

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="input-mini" type="text">
    <span class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">
        <button class="btn">
            <i class="icon icon-chevron-up">s</i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn">
            <i class="icon icon-chevron-down">d</i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

*And, even if you don't want css :  just to fix the view (because buttons are big [bigger than input]):*

**CSS :**

```
.btn-group-vertical > .btn{
   height: 1em;
   padding: 0px 6px 13px;
}
```

Comment: Thx I was aware of the vertical button group. Was just hoping there was a way to size the buttons to match the height of the input without adding custom CSS.